# Draw a simple textbox in java?

Tags: java, textbox

I want to create a simple textbox like in the picture in java. It displays a short text and close after a short time or we can click close button. Thanks first :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..a short text and close after a short time ..

Tool tip

> ..or we can click close button.

`JTextArea` or `JEditorPane` in `JDialog` (possibly also adding a `javax.swing.Timer` to close it).

Answer (score 0):

I've just resolved my problem using a simple JLabel and I use timer running in other thread to close it. Thanks guys :)

Comment: @ nXqd, Actually, I think Andrew solved it with his suggestion which is why you should accept his answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use a glass pane to paint over other content.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html